# HTML table cell td click event using id

Tags: html, events, html-table, click

I have a HTML Table as following.

HTML code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.column_data -->
<td id="dataCell" data-bind="text: result"></td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I would like to catch the first click event on the table cell and highlight that particular cell with red border.

And on second click I am supposed to open a pop up menu with two options(say option1, option2).

JS:

```
var clickCount = 0;

      $("#dataCell").click(function () {
        clickCount == 0 ? 1 : clickCount;
      });
```

I am not sure why it is not hitting into the click event :(, I have tried this for quite a long time. If I can get anyhelp it would be useful to move forward.

Comment: Access that id with its parent tag or class or id like `$('table tbody tr td')`

Answer (score 0):

First define an id for table also and try the following code:

```
var clickCount = 0;
$(document).on("click", "#tableId #dataCell", function(e) {
     alert("clicked");
     clickCount == 0 ? 1 : clickCount;
});
```